# iiyama ProLite B2712HDS with ATI Sapphire HD 4850x2

Tags: display, hdmi, amd-radeon

I've just bought a iiyama ProLite B2712HDS 27" monitor and upon hooking this up to my ATI 4850x2 over HDMI I cannot get the screen resolution to setup correctly! If I use ATI's CCC, I can set it to 1080p but I get a black border around the screen of about an inch. My first thought was to use the auto tuner button but this doesn't seem to do anything! Does anyone have the same screen and has encountered similar issues connecting to a pc over HDMI?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into catalyst and change a setting for scaling options (digital flat panel) and increase it to 0% maxed towards Overscan.  This should make the screen fullsize kinda like a zoom function but it is 1080p.  If it wont let you do it by jumping back when you let go of the mouse then you need to un-install your driver and re-install your latest ATI drivers, failing that go to your cards site and get theirs, once reinstalled you should be able to make the changes stick.  My cards are XFX and I got their driver, it worked, even allowed me to change refresh rates but still cant have 75hz at 1080p. GRR!